# Angular table performance

Tags: jquery, angularjs

im trying to draw my table more efficient way
I have some directive for cells which are complex. They consist of ng-repeats for example.
I noticed ng-repeat creates new scope. Ive got some nested ng-repeat wchich results in tons of scopes.
I noticed the linking is veeery slow.
How to optimize that?

Comment: please show some love and post some code, code is always hepful!

Comment: ng-repeat doesn't create new scope. Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AngularJS 1.3 you can use `One-time binding` operator `::`

for example like this on ng-repeat

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item.name}};</li>
</ul>
```

for more details you can see link below:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression